# Question on Lead record sharing with Partners in the Partner Community

Tags: partner-communities, apex-managed-sharing

Use case detail:

- Partners can create Leads and view Leads that are assigned to the
  Partner thru the Partner Community
- Partner creates a Lead (e.g. Dan Cook)
- Partner has visibility to the Lead due to record ownership
- Internal user wants to share a Lead (e.g. Brian Jones), where the ownership is not the Partner

The proposed implementation plan is:

- Create a Look Up to User field called ‘Share With’ label and assign the Partner User to the field
- Leverage Apex Managed Sharing (write code) to provide Read Only access to the specific Partner User (that is populated in Share With field)

Is there an option to avoid apex managed sharing for this use case?

Salesforce configuration include:
Organization-Wide Defaults for Lead is Private